# Better SQL script to create a table of aggregated results arranged in a calendar-like format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

What the data looks like in the database:

```
id | source | createTime
------------------------
1  | pc     | 2019-01-02
2  | mobile | 2019-01-02
3  | pc     | 2019-02-01
```

What I want is a tabulated result for pc and mobile counts based on the days for each month for a given year:

```
jan_pc | jan_mobile | feb_pc | feb_mobile
-----------------------------------------
0      | 0          | 1      | 0         <- first row is day 1
-----------------------------------------
1      | 1          | 0      | 0         <- second row is day 2, etc.. all the way to day 31
-----------------------------------------
```

This is the SQL script I'm currently using (partial shown), where each row represents a day of the month starting from day 1, and the columns are the months + pc/mobile count starting from January, in this example I use a union to create two rows representing days 1 and 2.

```
select top (1)
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=1 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '1_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=1 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '1_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=2 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '2_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=2 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '2_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=3 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '3_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=3 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '3_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=4 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '4_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=4 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '4_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=5 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '5_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=5 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '5_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=6 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '6_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=6 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '6_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=7 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '7_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=7 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '7_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=8 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '8_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=8 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '8_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=9 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '9_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=9 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '9_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=10 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '10_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=10 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '10_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=11 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '11_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=11 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '11_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=12 and day(createtime)=1 and source='1') as '12_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=12 and day(createtime)=1 and source='2') as '12_M'
from customer

union all

select top (1)
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=1 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '1_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=1 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '1_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=2 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '2_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=2 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '2_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=3 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '3_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=3 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '3_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=4 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '4_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=4 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '4_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=5 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '5_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=5 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '5_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=6 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '6_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=6 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '6_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=7 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '7_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=7 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '7_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=8 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '8_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=8 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '8_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=9 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '9_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=9 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '9_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=10 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '10_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=10 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '10_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=11 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '11_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=11 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '11_M',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=12 and day(createtime)=2 and source='1') as '12_P',
(select
    count(source)
from customer where year(createtime)=2019 and month(createtime)=12 and day(createtime)=2 and source='2') as '12_M'
from customer
```

I'm sure there is a better way - any suggestions?

Comment: Does your source column contains only 2 values (i.e. 'pc' & 'mobile')  or it can by more than that ?

Comment: I would simply select month, day, source, and count (i.e. group by month, day, and source) from the table and then do the layout in my GUI layer (app or Website).

Comment: @SureshGajera yes it will only have 2 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT DATEPART(YY,createTime) AS [YearPart],DATEPART(DD,createTime) AS 
    DayNum,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH,createTime),1,3),'_',source) AS Mon_Src
    FROM Customer
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    COUNT(Mon_Src)
    FOR Mon_Src IN ([Jan_pc],[Jan_mobile],[Feb_pc],[Feb_mobile],[Mar_pc], 
                    [Mar_mobile],[Apr_pc],[Apr_mobile],[May_pc],[May_mobile],[Jun_pc],[Jun_mobile], 
                    [Jul_pc],[Jul_mobile],[Aug_pc],[Aug_mobile],[Sep_pc],[Sep_mobile],[Oct_pc], 
                    [Oct_mobile],[Nov_pc]
                   ,[Nov_mobile],[Dec_pc],[Dec_mobile])
    ) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Picking this as the correct answer but the one above by @Venkataraman also works.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to have a separate Calendar Table, which will make all your date related queries simpler.
2. You need to pivot the results to get the daynumber and corresponding sales.

I have put sample code below for your needs. I have put a simple calendar table for one year. You might need a more rows for Calendar table based on the sales data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #calendar(DateValue DATE)
CREATE TABLE #sales(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) not null, [source] VARCHAR(10), CreateTime DATE)


INSERT INTO #sales([source],CreateTime)
values('pc','2019-01-02'),('mobile','2019-01-02'),('pc','2019-02-01');

DECLARE @s DATE = '2019-01-01' 
DECLARE @e DATE = '2019-12-31' 

-- Loading Calendar Table
;WITH CTE_Numbers AS
(
SELECT TOP (1000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects 
)
INSERT INTO #calendar(DateValue)
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @s, @e) + 1) 
 d = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @s))
 FROM CTE_Numbers;

 SELECT DayNumber, [Jan_PC],[Jan_Mobile],[Feb_PC],[Feb_Mobile]
 FROM
 (
 SELECT DATEPART(Day,DateValue) as DayNumber, CONCAT(LEFT(DATENAME(Month, DateValue),3),'_', s.[source]) as SourceMonth, s.ID
 FROM #calendar AS c
 INNER JOIN #sales AS s
 ON s.CreateTime = c.DateValue) AS ps
 PIVOT 
 (
    COUNT(ps.ID)
    FOR ps.[sourceMonth] IN ([Jan_pc],[Jan_mobile],[Feb_pc],[Feb_Mobile])
 )AS pvt
 ORDER BY DayNumber;
```

The result is given below for your reference:

```
+-----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
| DayNumber | Jan_PC | Jan_Mobile | Feb_PC | Feb_Mobile |
+-----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
|         1 |      0 |          0 |      1 |          0 |
|         2 |      1 |          1 |      0 |          0 |
+-----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+
```

**References**
- [Loading Calendar Table](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [Loading Number Table](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)